# How do I get all but the last entry of each group with pandas groupby?

Tags: pandas

I was hoping something like this would work to get all but the last entry of a group:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""A B
1 a
1 b
2 c
3 z
3 z
3 z"""), sep="\s+")
g = df.groupby("A")
g.head(g.size() - 1)
```

I'd like to do it with vectorized functions or be told why it is not possible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `duplicated`

```
out = df[df.duplicated('A',keep='last')]
Out[50]: 
   A  B
0  1  a
3  3  z
4  3  z
```

Or `tail`

```
df.drop(g.tail(1).index)
Out[54]: 
   A  B
0  1  a
3  3  z
4  3  z
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy way along your train of thought, try `lambda`:

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1])
```

Less easy way, use `transform`:

```
g = df.groupby('A')
df[g['A'].transform('size')-1 > g.cumcount()]
```

But easiest and fastest:

```
df[~df.duplicated('A', keep='last')]
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer and have upvoted it, but using a lambda is slow and non-vectorized :)

Comment: With `cumcount` could use the `ascending` argument that way you don't need to worry about size. `df[df.groupby('A').cumcount(ascending=False).ne(0)]`